# Коли і як виникло прислів'я "де два українці, там три гетьмани"?

Tags: фразеологізми, історія-мови

Чи не підкаже шановне панство, коли вперше фіксується прислів'я "де два українці, там три гетьмани"? Також цікавить хоча б приблизний час винекнення цієї фрази.

приклад ужитку: https://www.radiosvoboda.org/a/918665.html

Спробував сам шукати джерела, але найдавніше що наґуґлилося - це приклад ужитку і ще пара посилань на google books кінця 90-х, в яких вислів використовується як вже щось стале, загальновідоме.

Comment: Можу зазначити, що натрапляв на схожий вираз _two Jews, three opinions_.